# entity framework manual migration after automatic

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, migration

I'm in the following situation:

- I'm using Entity Framework, with auto-create database, and auto-migration
- There are already multiple versions (1 and 2) of my product already deployed and out there
- for my next version (3) I want to add an explicit migration
- I want others to be able to upgrade their version from 1 and 2 to version 3

When I add my explicit migration with Add-Migration [update-name], it creates a file with a timestamp [now].
Upgrades from version 1 and 2 to version 3 work, first doing automigration, then the explicit migration, as long as version 1 and 2 have been installed/run -before- the timestamp of my explicit migration.

From what I understand, this is because the AutoMigration entries in the database created with versions 1 and 2 have timestamps before the timestamp of my explicit migration, so EF knows it needs to perform my explicit migration.

But if version 1 or 2 is installed/run **after** I created the explicit migration, say next month, I still would like users to be able to upgrade to version 3. However, the explicit migration is not triggered. I think because the AutoMigrations triggered by running version 1 and 2 for the first time generated timestamps **after** the timestamp created for my manual migration.

**UPDATE**

I think my problem is I still need an autoMigration first, immediately -before- my explicit migration. 
The first autoMigration is needed to bring the database from whatever previous automigrated version to the state of version 2 (before my explicit migration), and then do explicit migration to version 3.
It seems there the order of the "timestamp" does matter then, because if there is already an AutoMigration in database with a higher "timestamp" than my explicit migration label,
the new automigration is not performed first and migration fails. If I label my explicit migration with a "higher" timestamp, an automigration+explicit migration are performed correctly.

**example**
if my database already contains an automigration that was created in the past, say, in __MigrationHistory, an Id

```
201610260843258_AutomaticMigration
```

Then after an update-database, the successfully updated table contains:

```
201610250843258_AutomaticMigration
201610260852133_v891_AutomaticMigration
201610260852134_v891
```

where **201610260852134_v891** is my explicit migration.

however, if the "initial" automatic migration was generated with a "timestamp" that would be sorted after the prefix of my explicit migration Id, for example

```
201610270843258_AutomaticMigration
```

then the update-database fails, because it doesn't understand it needs to do another AutoMigration first; so it just tries to apply my explicit migration.

So my current solution (or hack if you will) is to from now on disable automigrations, always create explicit migrations, and manually rename their Id's to something that is always ranked "higher" than any automigration that may have been done in the future (that is, an automigration that has a generated Id that would rank higher than my explicit migration).

If anyone has any suggestion or comment on this workaround, please feel free! :)

Comment: EF does not look at the timestamps - that is purely for labeling. It looks (sequentially) for records in the __MigrationHistory table of the target database and if the key matches, it is skipped, if it doesn't then the migration is applied and a record indicating so is added. [See here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood)

Comment: Thanks. It does make thinks more clear, and I updated my problem with what I think is at least a workaround for my problem